# Is it possible to use custom fonts in Highcharts?

Tags: fonts, highcharts

I've tried adding custom font to my chart using

`dataLabels: {
                        style: {
                            fontFamily: '\'kabelblack\',
                        },`

as this was the method stated on a similar question on here but this breaks my script. I've also tried calling the font using `'Kabel-Black'` (as defined in my CSS font-face) but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [datalabels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) return value inside any div with class, then set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.useHTML) as true and define CSS styles for datalabel's class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fontFamily` code does not have a closing single quote. The font must also exist on the server. If you are making your own export server that font must also exist there as well.